# Where can I find dynamic_cast source?

Tags: c++

Is dynamic_cast a built-in of C++? I looked through GCC headers, /usr/include/c++/4.4.7 in my installment and could not find its implementation.

Comment: I believe it's a keyword.

Comment: Yes, it's a keyword. Any good book or other reference on C++ should tell you what is and isn't part of the core language.

Comment: That actually doesn't prevent it from being implemented using (admittedly non-portable) C++ source. At least the dynamic part, that is, the static part (are the surce and target types even related?) has to be done by the compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dynamic_cast` is built in to the language. It does require an implementation, but there is no standardised location for the implementation.

In the gcc tool-chain, you can find some helper functions for the implementation in [libsupc++](https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/tree/master/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++). You might also be interested in reading the ABI documentation for your platform -- for example, the [x64 C++ ABI](http://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/) indicates the required storage layout and provides some sample code.

Comment: That doesn't contain the implementation of dynamic_cast, it contains the implementation of the helper functions used by GCC's implementation of dynamic_cast, which is not the same thing. Those helper functions may well be what the OP is looking for, though.

Comment: @hvd: tried to fix the language, and added a pointer to x64 abi (I hope still current)

Comment: Looks good to me. Re-reading my comment, it may come across as a smart-ass remark, but to clarify, there are definitely bits of `dynamic_cast` that you can only find in the compiler sources, not any run-time library, a simple example being compile-time errors for invalid cast attempts ("error: cannot dynamic_cast 's' (of type 'struct S*') to type 'struct T*' (source type is not polymorphic)")

Comment: @hvd: sure, I agree. Furthermore, the compiler is free to optimize dynamic_cast based on any information it may be able to deduce so an individual cast site may not need any function call. So, as usual, it's Not Quite That Simple :) .

Answer (score 1):

That's because it's a [keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword). It's part of the compiler. You won't find the implementation like that and I don't see why it would be helpful. Why do you *want* the implementation? Perhaps we can help find an alternate solution.